# Historic spatial extent of Beirut, Lebanon?

Tags: geospatial, government, historical, city

I am looking for historic extent data for the city of Beirut, in Lebanon.

I would like to show the growth of the city over time, from 1950 to today. The data are to be used in a web visualisation to aid story-telling and therefore do not necessarily have to be from an authoritative source. Ideally I'd like to show the growth of the city one decade at a time, so 1950 - 1960 - 1970 - 1980 and so on.

I've looked at a number of data sources - including GADM and a number of 'GIS data aggregator' sites. Whilst finding contemporary boundaries isn't too difficult, finding historic data for comparison purposes is proving a challenge. Any spatial format is fine, even Excel with coordinates would be workable.

Comment: If this is likely to be open data then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Have you tried extracting the info from archive satellite imagery? Look for the Corona images. There is an online repository for the east Mediterranean but don't have the link now. You can get the 60's imagery at least this way.